# Stretch iframe from top of body to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, class

This seems like a pretty basic question that probably has a really simple answer but I've been working on it for a while and can't seem to get it right.

I want to make a PDF in an iframe stretch from the bottom of the header to the bottom of the page. So far I have the iframe starting at the bottom of the header but I can't get it to stretch the exactly the bottom.

I've tried moving things around so that the header is in it's own body, so that everything is in the same body, so that only the iframe is in a body, and so that everything has their own body. I've tried a lot of things. Here is my code, any ideas? Thanks!

```js
// This script is for the Issues dropdown
function dropdown() {
    document.getElementById("issuesDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.bannerDropdown')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /*background:
  linear-gradient(27deg, #002856 5px, transparent 5px) 0 5px,
  linear-gradient(207deg, #002856 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 0px,
  linear-gradient(27deg, #003e87 5px, transparent 5px) 0px 10px,
  linear-gradient(207deg, #003e87 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 5px,
  linear-gradient(90deg, #002856 10px, transparent 10px),
  linear-gradient(#1d1d1d 25%, #002856 25%, #003e87 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 75%, #003e87 75%, #003e87);*/
  background-color: #002e63;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}

.inFullscreenButton {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 140px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #003e63;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 48px;
  width: 9.5%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 2px solid #001463;
  border-top: 2px solid #003e63;
  border-left: 2px solid #003e63;
}

.fullscreenButton {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 147px;
  left: 251px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #003e63;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 48px;
  width: 102px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 2px solid #001463;
}

.hideText {
  color: transparent;
}

.fullscreenArticle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 84.1699849%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

.article {
  width: 50%;
  height: 82%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #003e63;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bannerText {
  width: 33.34%;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #003e63;
  border-bottom: .2em solid #001463;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 18pt;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 150%;
}

.bannerText:hover {
  color: #808080;
}

.normalText {
  z-index: 1;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: .5em;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: .2em solid #001463;
    background: #003e63;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #1958a0}

.bannerDropdown {
    background-color: #003e63;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18pt;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}

.bannerDropdown:hover, .bannerDropdown:focus {
    color: #808080;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<body>
<div id='banner' class='banner'>
  <img id='bannerimage' class='banner' src='banner1920x130.png' alt='The Spartan Spotlight' onclick="location.href='main.html'">
  <div id='issues' class='bannerText' style='float: left;' class='dropdown'>
    <div onclick="dropdown()" class="bannerDropdown">Issues</div>
    <div id="issuesDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Issue 3 - Coming soon...</a>
      <a href="issue-2.html">Issue 2 - December 2017</a>
      <a href="issue-1.html">Issue 1 - November 2017</a>
      <a href="#">Older Issues</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='contact-us' class='bannerText' style='float: right;' onclick="location.href='style.css'">Contact Us</div>
  <div id='the-team' class='bannerText' style='margin: 0 33.3%;' onclick="location.href='style.css'">The Team</div>
</div>

<iframe id='article' class='article' src="issue-1.pdf#toolbar=0&view=fitH" type='application/pdf' frameborder=0></iframe>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your banner image at top has 130px height, the banner row below it is about 36px height, you can use something this for iframe height to fill remaining height of the page to bottom:

```
.article {
  // ...
  height: calc(100% - (130px + 36px + 8px)); //8px is for padding/margins...
  // ...
}
```

Update:
As you said in your comment, if the heights are not fixed, you can use `display: table;`and `table-row` for this purpose as here:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.container
{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 99.5%; /* provide a little space at bottom, you may use: calc(100% - 5px) */
}

.row { display: table-row; }

.article {
  /*display: table-row;*/
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%; 
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: none; 
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="div1" class="row" style="height:130px; background: blue;">banner image...</div>

  <iframe class="row article" src="" type="application/pdf">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't work because the banner isn't always 130 pixels. The actual image is, but I have it set so that the banner's width is always 100%, and the height to width ratio is always the same so when the window's size changes so does the banner's height.

Comment: @Andrew ok, if it's size is dynamic, please check updated answer and provide your feedback